# null pointer (java.io.File) exception dissappears while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, file-io

I have an application which throws this error (happens only with xlsx-files):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:222)
at de.mpicbg.tds.core.ExcelLayout.openWorkbook(ExcelLayout.java:75)
```

The method 'openWorkbook' looks like this:

```
    private void openWorkbook() throws IOException {
    File excelFile = new File(fileName);

    timestamp = excelFile.lastModified();

    // open excel file
    if (fileName.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
        InputStream excelStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(excelFile));
        this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook((excelStream));

    } else {
        this.workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(excelFile)));
    }
}
```

If I execute everything in debug mode, everything goes smoothly and the error message does not appear. I don't have any explanation for this behaviour nor any idea how to fix it.
Can anybody help?

Comment: What version Java? You might have to look in `File.java` source.

Comment: You have `null` `fileName` somehow.

Comment: Where does `fileName` initialized?

Comment: @mattb It must be the line involving a `File` constructor: `File excelFile = new File(fileName);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says your `fileName` is `null`

If you cannot reproduce this when debugging you can add a log message at the start of you method.

```
System.out.println("The fileName is `" + fileName+"`");
```

Instead of using a field which may or may not be set, I suggest you use a parameter.

```
private void openWorkbook(String fileName) throws IOException {
    assert fileName != null;
```

Comment: you might be right. the filename should be delivered with a ChangeEvent from a GUI component. For some reason, I assume that the component delivers null...